# How to know if hub-gears provide fitting transmissions?

Tags: internally-geared-hub

I want to get a decent bike for my daily trip to work and other trips.

My daily trip to work is around 15km in total and the terrain is quite flat (except for a small hill and a few underpasses). The infrastructure is excellent.

I want to following features in my bike: 28", hub gears (7), front suspension. However, the supply of local dealerships featuring bikes with those qualities is virtually zero. So I am leaning towards ordering a bike from an online store.

However, I'm a bit scared of 8 gear transmissions, since the last bike I owned had one and the 8th gear "ran out of resistance" when I was only going 15-20km/h. However, I'd like to be comfortably riding around 20-30km/h.

**Without test riding, how can I know that the bike will have the right transmission ratio?**

For example [this bike](https://www.bike-discount.de/en/cube-travel-pro-denim-n-silver) has a "Travel Pro's Shimano 8-speed hub gear". But when I google for that, I find no further information (just other bikes using it) and also on shimano's website I didn't have any more luck. I found [another gear](https://www.rosebikes.fi/shimano-nexus-inter-8-sg-c6000-8-coaster-gear-hub-749480) that has a ratio of "307%", but I don't know what to do that information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing gear ratios on different bike types](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13191/comparing-gear-ratios-on-different-bike-types)
If you know what the specifics of the other 8 gear bike that "ran out of resistance" you know that that gear ratio is too low.

Comment: Also, you could check if there are bikes that don't match all the desired qualities (e.g. no suspension) as that has no effect on the gear ratio. You could then at least try out if a specific gear hub works for you.

Comment: For the Travel Pro bike you linked to you can find more info on the hub by searching for the hub name, which is "Shimano Nexus SG-C6001-8D". You will then find [the Shimano product page](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/nexus-c6000-int8/SG-C6001-8D.html).

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke that's a great idea.

Comment: Keep in mind though that the front chain ring tooth count(s) (and the wheel size and crank length to a lesser degree) do play a role in the gear ratio, so try to match that when looking for other bikes to test.

Comment: BTW, you can choose the model you want online, and go to your local dealer and order it there. You still likely won't be able to try it before commiting to buy, but buying through a local dealer gets you better support after purchase, which, at 15 km/day is going to be important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find out what your cog combination is (front and rear), what your gear hub is, and what tires you have, and then go to https://www.gear-calculator.com/. Plug the numbers and see what speeds you get. So, for the Cube bike you mentioned, you will get this (@80 crank rotations per minute): [Cube Travel Pro Shimano Alfine-8](https://www.gear-calculator.com/?GR=SHA8&KB=46&RZ=22&UF=2295&TF=80&SL=2.6&UN=KMH&DV=teeth).

Cadence is relevant. 80 rpm may or may not be too much for you. You can determine the cadence you're confortable at by backtracking from your previous bike: you know the "max speed". If you find out the tires and cogs it used, you can use the same calculator to determine your confort-cadence, and once you know that correct your calculation for your new bike.

Personally, I find about 75 - 80 rpm (and an easy gear) a confortable cadence if I want to cruise avoiding sweating. If I want to go fast and really put effort I ride at >95 rpm.